# generate_series not working in single user mode

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

A table is not being populated with generate_series for below.

```
backend> create table t1 (i int, j int);
backend> insert into t1 values (generate_series(1,200000), generate_series(1,200000));
backend> select count(*) from t1;
backend>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `INSERT ... VALUES (...), (...), ... ;` syntax can accept multiple rows but you can't put a table generating function inside a row.

You need to use the `INSERT .. SELECT .. FROM .. ;` syntax and put the table generating function in the `FROM` clause:

```
insert into t1 (i, j) 
select g.i, g.i 
from generate_series(1, 200000) as g(i) ;
```